# Баг компилятора при компилировании Bullet Physics

Tags: gcc, mingw, c++

Сегодня наконец-то понял, как собрать программу! Нажал на кнопку и "БАЦ!", а компилятор жалуется на:

> ...\bullet\BulletDynamics\Character\btKinematicCharacterController.cpp|382|internal compiler error: Segmentation fault|

И всё бы ладно, но в гугле сказано, что это баг компилятора, но у других же собирается без бага!
Самое забавное, что компилятор ругается на закрывающую скобку, но ошибки на самом деле нет (и это не смешно)...

Была такая же ошибка в предыдущем файле, но для того кода было решение.